# How to type a small fraction in Word 2007 equation editor?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

In Word 2007’s equation editor, I can enter “1/2” and I will get a properly formatted fraction. However, there is another kind of fraction that uses a smaller font size. How do I type that one using the keyboard alone?

[image: Screenshot]

I notice that if I switch to linear mode, I get a small box displayed:

[image: Screenshot]

Using the clipboard, I find that this is the same box (U+25A1) that I also get if I type “\box”. Despite, typing “\box(1/2)” still turns into a normal-size fraction and not the small fraction.

How do I type the small fraction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that `\box` *does* insert something special, albeit something that *defaults* to the normal font size, but it has a feature which enables the following sequence of keypresses to make it small:

- **Type `\box(1/2)` followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>.** The fraction is inserted and looks “large” at first.
- **Press the <kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow) key.** This brings the cursor into a position where the entire fraction is highlighted in gray. This indicates that `\box` has inserted an extra element (and then a normal fraction inside of it). (With the “normal” fraction, the Left Arrow key instead navigates directly into the denominator.)
- **Press the <kbd>Context</kbd> key followed by <kbd>D</kbd>** (“Decrease Argument Size”). This command is not available if just one argument is highlighted in gray.

  [image]
- **Press the <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow) key** to restore the cursor position and continue typing.

This finding has several interesting corollaries:

- You can use `\box` to reduce the font size of anything, not just fractions. You can type `\box\sqrt(x)` followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Context</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, and it’ll reduce the font size of the entire square-root.
- Using Copy & Paste to copy the `\box` character (U+25A1) also copies information on the font size. Hence, copying and pasting a `\box` that is already set to smaller font size maintains the small font size.
- You can choose more than just two font sizes. It seems to me that there are 5 different font size settings — the default, two smaller ones and two “larger” ones. With a simple fraction, the two “larger” ones are the same size as default; but if you put a `\box` inside a `\box` that reduces font size, you can use this to “restore” the larger font size, as in this entirely fictitious example:

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I notice from your initial testing if you copy and paste the Unicode character into a new equation and follow it with the equation e.g (1/2) then the small fraction type is correctly inserted. This is not the most fluent way to insert this fraction type using the keyboard, however you could translate this into a simple macro and bind it to a key combination.